# Why do Spring CRUD repository updates return int, but count long?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I understand that counting many entries in a database may return more than int_max entries and therefore [Spring CRUD repository's count()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#count()) method has long as return type.

However, assuming that the DB contains more than int_max entries and I issue an update/delete query for all entries, I'd also need a long to return the number of updated/deleted entries.

Therefore I defined my Spring Data method as

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from AUDIT_CREATE_SAVINGS_EASY_ACCESS_ACCOUNT where timestamp < :cutOff")
fun deleteByTimestampBefore(@Param("cutOff") cutOff: Instant): Long
```

To my surprise the invocation of this method causes a stack trace

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type! Offending method: public abstract long de.foo.FooRepository.deleteByTimestampBefore(java.time.Instant); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type!
[...]
```

I guess it makes sense since [JPA Query's executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate--) method returns int, but I am puzzled why that is the case.

In any way, shouldn't count and update-queries return the same type - i.e. int or long if int is too small?

Comment: "Should" they? :shrug: But they don't, so... it's unclear what kind of answer you're looking for.